# jq element matching with in a nested array

Tags: jq

I have an array of array as following

```
[
  {
    "devices": [
      {
        "files": [
          {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "file"
          }
        ],
        "path": "/tmp/file1"
      },
      {
        "files": [
          {
            "id": "3",
            "type": "file"
          }
        ],
        "path": "/tmp/file2"
      }
    ],
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "devices": [
      {
        "files": [
          {
            "id": "4",
            "type": "file"
          }
        ],
        "path": "/tmp/tfile"
      },
      {
        "files": [
          {
            "id": "5",
            "type": "file"
          }
        ],
        "path": "/var/mfile"
      }
    ],
    "name": "b"
  }
]
```

I'm looking for output like this

```
a /tmp/file1 2
a /tmp/file2 3
b /tmp/tfile 4
b /var/mfile 5
```

What I have tried

```
cat myfile.json | jq '.[] | "\(.name), \(.devices[].path) \(.devices[].files[].id)"'
```

and result is

```
"a, /tmp/file1 2"
"a, /tmp/file2 2"
"a, /tmp/file1 3"
"a, /tmp/file2 3"
"b, /tmp/tfile 4"
"b, /var/mfile 4"
"b, /tmp/tfile 5"
"b, /var/mfile 5"
```

but I'm unable to select a key for the value is in parent map.
I want to for each of the elements matching name == a, for each of a[path], get a[path][id].

Comment: How is `1 2 4 5` possible?  file IDs are 2, 3 in first object

Answer (score 1):

- Using `.devices[]` twice will iterate over the same `.devices` twice, giving you the cartesian product. Extract from within one iteration.
- You can nest string iterpolation; otherwise collect into an array (here you'd need `,` as separator) and use `join(" ")` to concatenate
- Use the `-r` (or `--raw-output`) flag to output raw text

```
jq -r '.[] | "\(.name) \(.devices[] | "\(.path) \(.files[].id)")"'
```

```json
a /tmp/file1 2
a /tmp/file2 3
b /tmp/tfile 4
b /var/mfile 5
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/leoNQbO3oBc)